# How to show the commutator of $SO(n)$ is itself?

Tags: abstract-algebra, lie-groups

I am not very familiar with Lie groups, but I want to show that the commutator subgroup of $SO(3)$ is itself. I have looked up many different sources, and it seems to me that almost all of them require some notion of Lie algebra, so I am wondering if it is possible to show this without much knowledge of Lie groups.

Comment: There's a commonly given geometric proof based on the transitive action of $G = SO(3)$ on $S^2$. If all you need is the fact that the commutator subgroup $G'$ is $G$ itself, you can show that directly without too much difficulty. Show, for example, that any $G^{\text{ab}} = G/G' = 0$ starting with the fact that any $g\in G$ is diagonalizable.

Comment: It seems that not all $g\in SO(3)$ are diagonalizable in $\mathbb R$. Do you mean in $\mathbb C$? @anomaly

Comment: Yes, over $\mathbb{C}$. (Diagonalizability generally fails over fields that aren't algebraically closed.)

Comment: Your title question and body question are different.  Are you interested in showing $SO(n)$ is simple (which is false when $n = 1,2,4$, or are you trying to show the commutator subgroup is all of $SO(n)$ (which is false when $n=1,2$)?

Comment: Hi, I changed the title (though doing so might be against your will, the previous title are not compatible with the body question and it seems you are not coming back to clarify)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can show directly that the commutator subgroup of $SO(n)$ is $SO(n)$ only for $n\ge 3$.

Now assume $n\ge 3$. In general, we know that every $A \in SO(n)$ can be written as $A = P BP^T$, where $P \in SO(n)$ and $B$ is block diagonal, with block of the form

$$E(\theta) = \begin{bmatrix} \cos \theta & \sin\theta \\ -\sin\theta & \cos\theta \end{bmatrix}$$

Geometrically, it just mean that all $SO(n)$ elements corresponds to rotations of two planes $L_1, L_2, \cdots$, where each $L_i$'s are mutually orthogonal.

Now it suffices to show that $B$ lie in the commutator subgroup. By induction, it suffices to show that

$$C = \begin{bmatrix} E(\theta) & 0 \\ 0 & I_{n-2} \end{bmatrix}$$

lies in the commutator subgroup. It is easy to show that $E(\theta)$ can be written as $ABAB$, where $A, B$ are reflections. Then $A = A^{-1}$, $B= B^{-1}$ and so $E(\theta) = [A, B]$. Then we have $C = [\tilde A, \tilde B]$, where

$$\tilde A = \begin{bmatrix} A & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & I_{n-3} \end{bmatrix} \in SO(n)$$

(Note that $n\ge 3$ is used so that you can write down that $-1$. This is necessary as $\det A = -1$)

Comment: It seems you've proven that $SO(n)$ is simple for all $n\geq 3$, but $SO(4)$ is not simple.  What am I missing?

Comment: @JasonDeVito : That's a misread by me. I showed that the commutator group of $SO(n)$ is $SO(n)$. I (incorrectly) thought that this is what the OP is asking for.